# How to add colorful logo to PCB in Altium Designer?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, kicad, hardware

I was going through Twitter, and I found this PCB I want to know how they add the colorful logo to it and it can be done in Altium Designer.

[image]

Comment: I expect that that graphic was done in some general drawing/artwork program, not in Altium.

Answer (score 1):

It was likely created as CMYK (with white solder mask) or CMYW in a graphics program such as Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape (open source) and printed onto the PCB with a UV flat-bed printer.

The PCB rendering could be exported from Altium Designer as a layer to paint over in the graphics program.

Although such printers often have a UV-cured clear coat, the resulting print may not be fully resistant to typical harsh PCB cleaning solvents- you might have to use aqueous or no-clean flux, for example. The printers themselves are not very cheap- they are typically based on commercial inkjet heads repurposed into an industrial printing chassis.